# Автоматический ввод пароля в child_process для git

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, консоль

Всем привет!
Я пытаюсь с помощью *node.js* и его *child_process.exec* сделать автоматические **commit + push** в *BitBucket* в приватные репозитории, есть список сайтов, которые нужно пройти по списку, сделать **git add**, **git commit** и **git push**. С первыми двумя проблем нет, а вот с пушами есть проблема - требуется вводить username и password для каждого сайта.
Как это можно сделать автоматически? Я читал про stdout/stdin/exec/spawn - но пока не понял как их использовать?
Сейчас есть довольно топорный код - я собираю одну большую строку из **cd /home/site1 && git push && cd /home/site2 && git push** и тд, а потом использую ее в exec

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const fs = require("fs");

const fileData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("site.json", "utf-8"));

let gitStr = "cd /";

for (let item in fileData) {
  gitStr = `${gitStr} && cd /home/${fileData[item]} && git push -u origin master`;
}

exec(gitStr, (error, stdout, stdin, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stdout) {
    console.log("stdout ", stdout);
  }

  if (stdin) {
    console.log("Stdin", stdin);
  }
});
```

Я понимаю что метод топорный, но и задача пока стоит весьма простая - освободить руки от рутины.
Так вот, после выполнения данной команды терминал запрашивает ввести логин один раз, а потом ввести пароль для каждого сайта - как можно автоматически определить что нужно ввести и ввести это в терминал чтобы он не требовал от меня никаких действий?

Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776439/username-and-password-in-command-for-git-push

Comment: настало время наконец-то узнать о том, что существует ассиметричное шифрование и аутентификация по таки ключам.

Comment: Сторонний вопрос: почему не `libgit2`?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , если я правильно понимаю, речь об авторизации по ssh? Я просто не совсем понимаю как это работает в моем случае, можете дать ссылку на статью?

Comment: могу дать ссылку на [справку](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-ssh-and-two-step-verification/) с сайта bitbucket.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо, сделал по инструкции, все сработало! Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: Для тех кто ищет ответ - сделал ссылку на удаленный репозиторий не через https, а по ssh, по [инструкции bitbucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/) сгенерил ключи, добавил в аккаунт, и отправка git push стала проходить без проблем, без запроса пароля.